# Can we overide a textbox value in datagridview cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

i want to overide value in datagridviewcell.
I have Dropdownlist.when i select the dropdown item. textbox value should overide in datagridview cell. any suggestion.

```
//this particular code .pulls the vatrate from access database
dvgproductlist.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value = dt.Rows[i]["VATRate"].ToString();
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: @Shiny Post code of your gridview and it will be easy to say what you want...

Comment: dvgproductlist.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value = dt.Rows[i]["VATRate"].ToString();
this particular code .pulls the vatrate from access database

Comment: Shiny, what is the actual question? What isn't working?

Comment: Have you tried calling Refresh() on your DataGridView?

Answer (score 0):

From [`DataGridViewCell.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx) property, try refreshing the cell to fit the new value by adding this loc;

```
dvgproductlist.Rows[i].DataGridView.AutoResizeColumn(11, DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have tofind your control and then set a value for it like

```
   int EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
   ((TextBox)grdList.Rows[grdList.EditIndex].FindControl("textBox1")).Text = "Nasser Hadjloo";
```